# root ssh acccess is disabled and sudo user can not make root changes on vps Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh, sudo, root, sshd

I first created a sudo user from root ssh by using below commands on my Ubuntu 22 server:

```
adduser username
usermod -aG sudo username
```

Then, I disabled my Root login by going to `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` in root ssh and `PermitRootLogin=no` and restarted ssh service.

Now, when I ssh login with sudo user, I can not do most of root tasks. For example, can not edit sshd_config, can no install application, etc.

I have basic knowledge of Linux, so my questions are:

1- How to give my sudo user full privilege like root user?

2- How to change sshd_config file and restart ssh service with or without ssh access?

3- Can I edit sshd_config by php script? I am using CloudPanel

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Ubuntu does not allow a person to ssh in as `root`. If you were able to do this, your VPS provider has a custom version of Ubuntu that may have many other unique configurations in place. It may be better to get in touch with them if you cannot perform commands with `sudo` 

Comment: @matigo that is not correct. Ubuntu by default _does_ allow a user to ssh in as root, just not with _password authentication_. If you copy your ssh public key to root's authorized keys, then you can simply `ssh root@remote.machine`. This is precisely how some VPS providers provision their machines: you hand them your public key, and they will set it as `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` so you have an initial login.

Comment: root login is disabled. Also, private/public key login in sshd_config file is off. so I must first access sshd_config file to do anything

Comment: To be clear, with _by default_ I mean: with the default setting of `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`.

Comment: Not by default, I did disable it. Now I can not return to it with sudo user

Comment: ``sudo visudo''

Answer (score 0):

To execute one command with root privileges:

```
sudo command args ...
```

So editing the config file would be

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

To become root for a while

```
sudo su -
```

The latter executes the 'substitute user (`su`)' command, which needs root privileges, hence the sudo in front.

Comment: I already know about these and have tried them all. My sudo user can not edit config file.

Comment: @MattZ Then please clarify this in your question, because this isn't obvious at all from what you wrote. Show what you have done, and what happened: what do you see when you `sudo su -` or try to edit `sshd_config`.

Comment: I have disabled root access. Now I can not get it back from sudo user. I can not access my root ssh